# Python: Sorting Dictionary By Value or Key And Subsetting Result to Top Three Key-Value Pairs

Tags: python, list, sorting, dictionary, subset

**3 Questions:**

1. Is there a straightforward way for me to sort a dictionary by a)key or b)value in descending order without importing an outside package?
2. Easy way to select only the top 3 key-value pairs in a dictionary by value?
3. Sort dictionary by value and then by key in descending order?

**Question 1:**
I have the following dictionary below "output_dict_s1":

```
{'Sebastian Vettel': 0.6153846153846154, 'Lewis Hamilton': 0.8461538461538461, 'Kimi Raikkonen': 0.8181818181818182, 'Daniel Ricciardo': 0.25, 'Fernando Alonso': 0, 'Max Verstappen': 0.5, 'Nico Hulkenberg': 0, 'Valtteri Bottas': 0.5, 'Stoffel Vandoorne': 0, 'Carlos Sainz': 0, 'Pierre Gasly': 0, 'Kevin Magnussen': 0, 'Marcus Ericsson': 0, 'Esteban Ocon': 0, 'Sergio Perez': 0.14285714285714285, 'Charles Leclerc': 0, 'Lance Stroll': 0, 'Brendon Hartley': 0, 'Romain Grosjean': 0, 'Sergey Sirotkin': 0}
```

To sort the dictionary by value, I'm using an outside package.  It works but I want to know how to do it without a package.

```
output_dict_sorted = dict(sorted(output_dict_s1.items(), key = operator.itemgetter(1), reverse = True))
```

**Question 2:**
Now the sorted dictionary "output_dict_sorted" looks like this:

```
{'Lewis Hamilton': 0.8461538461538461, 'Kimi Raikkonen': 0.8181818181818182, 'Sebastian Vettel': 0.6153846153846154, 'Max Verstappen': 0.5, 'Valtteri Bottas': 0.5, 'Daniel Ricciardo': 0.25, 'Sergio Perez': 0.14285714285714285, 'Fernando Alonso': 0, 'Nico Hulkenberg': 0, 'Stoffel Vandoorne': 0, 'Carlos Sainz': 0, 'Pierre Gasly': 0, 'Kevin Magnussen': 0, 'Marcus Ericsson': 0, 'Esteban Ocon': 0, 'Charles Leclerc': 0, 'Lance Stroll': 0, 'Brendon Hartley': 0, 'Romain Grosjean': 0, 'Sergey Sirotkin': 0}
```

I want to subset the above dictionary so that only the top three key-value pairs show.  I've been using a roundabout way to do this.  Namely, converting that dictionary to a tuple list and then subsetting that tuple list to the first three indices and converting back to new dictionary.

```
output_dict_top3_s3 = list(output_dict_sorted_s2.items())[0:3]

for atuple in output_dict_top3_s3:
    print (atuple)
    output_dict_s4[atuple[0]] = atuple[1]
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: okay, what do you recommend instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Question 1: you do not need any external package, because you could use a lambda:

```
output_dict_sorted = dict(sorted(output_dict_s1.items(), key=lambda x: x[1],
                          reverse=True))
```

Question 2: you could directly limit the above instruction to the 3 first items, because `sorted` returns a list:

```
output_dict_top3 = dict(sorted(output_dict_s1.items(), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)[:3])
```

which gives as expected:

```
{'Lewis Hamilton': 0.8461538461538461,
 'Kimi Raikkonen': 0.8181818181818182,
 'Sebastian Vettel': 0.6153846153846154}
```

Comment: what about question 3?